# jQuery, how to don't restart the UL scroll animation

Tags: jquery, ajax, animation, scroll

I have a piece of jQuery code with an AJAX function that updates 2 UL lists when the data on a WordPress page is updated.

This works and the scrolling also works as I want it to. However, how can I make it so that when the data is updated, the scroll simply continues instead of the animation restarting from the first LI.

I have tried it with this code but it will not work:

```
var $lists = [$('#list01 ul').get(0), $('#list02 ul').get(0)];
var scrollPositions = [0, 0]; // Array om scrollposities bij te houden

function checkPostContent() {
    var postId = <?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>;
    var timer = null;

    // Scrol animatie voor de twee UL lijsten
    $lists.forEach(function(list, index) {
        var $this = $(list);
        var scrollTop = $this.scrollTop();
        var liHeight = $this.find('li:first').height();
        var scrollSpeed = 1000; // Scroll snelheid in milliseconden
        var pauseTime = 2000; // Pauze tijd tussen LI items in milliseconden

        function animateList() {
            $this.animate({
                scrollTop: '+=' + liHeight
            }, scrollSpeed, function() {
                $this.find('li:first').appendTo($this);
                $this.scrollTop(0);
                timer = setTimeout(animateList, pauseTime);
            }).delay(pauseTime);
        }

        timer = setTimeout(animateList, pauseTime);
        scrollPositions[index] = scrollTop; // Sla de scrollpositie op
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        timeout: 0,
        data: {
            action: 'check_post_content',
            post_id: postId,
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response === 'changed') {
                $.get(window.location.href, function(data) {
                    var $newContent = $('<div />').append(data).find('#list01, #list02');
                    $('#list01').html($newContent.filter('#list01').html());
                    $('#list02').html($newContent.filter('#list02').html());

                    // Selecteer de ingeladen lijsten opnieuw en hervat de scrollanimatie
                    $lists = [$('#list01 ul').get(0), $('#list02 ul').get(0)];
                    $lists.forEach(function(list, index) {
                        var $this = $(list);
                        $this.scrollTop(scrollPositions[index]);
                    });

                    checkPostContent();
                });
            } else {
                checkPostContent();
            }
        },
        error: function(req, err) {
            checkPostContent();
            console.log('my message' + err);
        }
    });
}
checkPostContent();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the scroll animation and put everything in 1 list instead of 2 lists and now everything works as it should.

Here is de code for it if other people wanna use something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $list = $('#list ul');
    var itemHeight = 37;
    var currentPosition = 0;
    var isAnimating = false;
    var numItems = <?php echo $total_rows; ?>;

    function checkPostContent() {
        var postId = <?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>;
        
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>',
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            timeout: 0,
            data: {
                action: 'check_post_content',
                post_id: postId,
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if (response === 'changed') {
                    $.get(window.location.href, function(data) {
                        var $newContent = $('<div />').append(data).find('#list ul');
                        
                        var $newList = $newContent.filter('#list ul');
                        $list.html($newList.html());
                        numItems = $list.find('li').length;
                        var listHeight = itemHeight * numItems;
                        $list.css('height', listHeight);
                        checkPostContent();
                    });
                } else {
                    checkPostContent();
                }
            },
            error: function(req, err) {
                checkPostContent();
                console.log('my message' + err);
            }
        });
    }

    checkPostContent();

    function animateList() {
        if (!isAnimating) {
            isAnimating = true;
            var newPosition = currentPosition - itemHeight;
            $list.animate({ top: newPosition }, 'slow', function() {
                currentPosition = newPosition;
                if (currentPosition < -($list.find('li').last().position().top - $list.parent().height())) {
                    // if the last item is showing, wait for a few seconds and then animate to the top
                    $list.delay(2000).animate({ top: 0 }, 'slow', function() {
                        currentPosition = 0;
                        $list.css('top', currentPosition);
                        isAnimating = false;
                    });
                } else {
                    isAnimating = false;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    setInterval(animateList, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Well done, simpler than my answer. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, to ensure the scroll animation doesn't restart when the data is updated, would be to update the content of the `LI` elements instead of replacing the entire `UL`.

That should allow the scroll animation to continue from its current position.

```js
var $lists = [$('#list01 ul').get(0), $('#list02 ul').get(0)];

function checkPostContent() {
    var postId = <?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>;
    var timer = null;

    // Scroll animation for the two UL lists
    $lists.forEach(function(list, index) {
        var $this = $(list);
        var scrollTop = $this.scrollTop();
        var liHeight = $this.find('li:first').height();
        var scrollSpeed = 1000; // Scroll speed in milliseconds
        var pauseTime = 2000; // Pause time between LI items in milliseconds

        function animateList() {
            $this.animate({
                scrollTop: '+=' + liHeight
            }, scrollSpeed, function() {
                $this.find('li:first').appendTo($this);
                $this.scrollTop(0);
                timer = setTimeout(animateList, pauseTime);
            }).delay(pauseTime);
        }

        timer = setTimeout(animateList, pauseTime);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        timeout: 0,
        data: {
            action: 'check_post_content',
            post_id: postId,
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response === 'changed') {
                $.get(window.location.href, function(data) {
                    var $newContent = $('<div />').append(data).find('#list01 ul li, #list02 ul li');
                    
                    // Replace the content of the existing LI elements
                    $('#list01 ul li').each(function(index, el) {
                        $(el).html($newContent.filter('#list01 ul li').eq(index).html());
                    });
                    $('#list02 ul li').each(function(index, el) {
                        $(el).html($newContent.filter('#list02 ul li').eq(index).html());
                    });

                    checkPostContent();
                });
            } else {
                checkPostContent();
            }
        },
        error: function(req, err) {
            checkPostContent();
            console.log('my message' + err);
        }
    });
}
checkPostContent();
```